# What is the chance of an 'invited manuscript submission' to be accepted?

Tags: journals, peer-review, paper-submission

I recently submitted a manuscript in a reliable journal in my field through 'invited manuscript' scheme. This is my first time to do such a thing since I mostly publish my paper on a regular submission. Of course, in general, the paper will be accepted based on its quality and merit. But, I was wondering if there is a difference in the chance of getting published when the submission was invited?

Answer (score 2):

In my experience from my own invited submissions to those of my colleagues' being invited means the journal trusts you to produce something worth publishing. Therefore, *unless you mess things up*, **your manuscript should be easily accepted for publication**.

However, that means you should be extra careful. Your public exposure relies on your publication record. You don't want to look bad. So make sure (i) the journal is truly respected in the area; (ii) nothing silly gets published. There is a tendency to slacken peer review whenever authors are invited to submit, meaning overlooked mistakes may more easily make it to final publication version. I'd recommend you find yourself **one very picky colleague** to peer review your manuscript on the side, prior to submission.

Comment: Thank you! I agree with you! At first, I was hesitant to submit in the journal since it is unusual to be invited to submit especially I don't have established a name on my field. But, the journal is a legitimate journal and I know well-established colleagues also submit their work to this journal. I submitted a paper on the journal for another reason as they will waive my publication article charge. My paper is still in review, let's see how the review goes.

Comment: Make sure it has a true ISI impact factor, DOI number, and indexed with WoS, etc. Too often, if it lacks any of these you might find that the paper doesn't "count" for your career records. I've fallen in such a trap, who hasn't.

Comment: I did. It has a good impact factor although not a Q1 it has a regular publication and published by a good publishing group. In addition, it is open-access.